# fetching data from table row and add as a parameter to the URL in ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a strut2 web application. I am new to ajax , JQuery and Json but trying to implement them in my project. In one of the web page I am displaying the record in a table format and the last column contain an image as show below. I have placed an anchor tag with image for the last column which has action call with some ID as a parameter.

[image: rows in table format]

Present Code::

```
 <a class="deleteUserIncomesJson" style="text-decoration: none" href="<tags:url action="deleteUserIncomesJson">
        <tags:param name="incomeID" value="%{incomeID}"/></tags:url>">
    <img width="20px" height="20px" src="<tags:url value="/image/Trash.png"/>" height="15"/>
</a>
```

Now I would like to convert this into an ajax call as below. Is this is correct way of achieving the action

```
 $(".deleteUserIncomesJson").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "deleteUserIncomesJson",
        data: {incomeID:incomeID},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(result)
                {
                    alert('record Deleted');
                    //code to repopulate the entire table
                }
        });
   });
```

If I write the ajax call I should remove the **HREF** from the anchor. doing that will disable the click-able action of my trashcan image.
also how can I pass the incomeID parameter which I unique to each row of the table to the ajax function upon performing click action to the image?

Can some one suggest me how to achieve this? in addition to the above requirements I would like to refresh the table entries with out refreshing the page.(refreshed table should not have the deleted row).

Updated:

I have run the Application in debug mode and incomeID is getting '0' which is wrong

[image: Debug Mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom `data-*` prefixed attributes to store `incomeID` related to element. Which can be later fetched using `.data()` in the current elements context i.e. `this` context

*HTML*

```
<a  class="deleteUserIncomesJson" 
    href="#" 
    data-incomeid="<tags:param name="incomeID" value="%{incomeID}"/>">
    <img width="20px" height="20px" src="<tags:url value="/image/Trash.png"/>" height="15"/>
</a>
```

*Script*

```
$(".deleteUserIncomesJson").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //Prevent default action
    var incomeid = $(this).data('incomeid'); //Fetch income id
    $.ajax({
        url: "deleteUserIncomesJson",
        data: {incomeID:incomeid},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(result)
        {
            alert('record Deleted');
            //code to repopulate the entire table
        }
    });
});
```

Note: The syntax might be incorrect `data-incomeid="<tags:param name="incomeID" value="%{incomeID}"/>`

Comment: thanks for the response @satpal. I have tried to implement that but no luck...particular action is getting called but the incomeID is coming as 0

Comment: @GhostRider, Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: i have posted the image where it show the incomeID in the action class as zero...because of that I am getting some null pointer exception as I am fetching the record based on that( which I will handle that later). other than that there is no other error on console. the entire html code is  around 255 lines can you please let me know which part of the code you want to attach in the original post?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try following?

```
$(".deleteUserIncomesJson").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var incomeid = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(0)").text(); //Fetch income id
$.ajax({
    url: "deleteUserIncomesJson",
    data: {"incomeID":incomeid},
    type: "POST",
    success: function(result)
    {
        alert('record Deleted');
        //code to repopulate the entire table
    }
});
```

});

For refreshing the page, you can clear out table contents and refill it again with fresh data. You can create functions for that.

Comment: Here is the errors which I am getting upon using the above mentioned code. 

WARNING: Could not find action or result: /SampleTC_test/deleteUserIncomesJson
No result defined for action com.hibernate.action.UserIncomeAction and result input

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you every one for your comments and suggestion. It was working fine now after doing these modification. I am not sure if this approach is correct or wrong but it is working fine with out any issues. I am still trying to figure out the part to refresh the table data with our refreshing the entire page.

Html Code:

```
 <a  class="deleteUserIncomesJson" href="#" id="{<tags:property value="incomeID"/>}" data="<tags:property value="incomeID"/>">
    <img width="20px" height="20px" src="<tags:url value="/image/Trash.png"/>" height="15"/>
 </a>
```

script:

```
$(".deleteUserIncomesJson").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var tempID = $(this).attr('data'); //Fetch income id        
    $.ajax({
        url: "deleteUserIncomesJson",
        data: {incomeID:tempID},
        type: "get",
        success: function(result)
        {
            alert('record Deleted');
            //code to repopulate the entire table
        }
    });
});
```

[image]